# How to implement resize event using event handler for border pane in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a post note application to build in javafx. I have a implement a method to resize my post note application using event handler. I am using border pane and need to resize that? Can anyone help?

Comment: You shouldn’t need to use events.  BorderPane will automatically resize its child nodes.

Comment: As already mentioned, a `BorderPane` will automatically resize its children. If you're having issues with this, please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] demonstrating the issue.